# Have + object + past participle vs Have + object + bare infinitive

Tags: infinitives, causative-have, experiential-have

1).  Cambridge dictionary [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-something-done) and Some of my friends are saying **have + object + bare infinitive** is used to talk about an experience

> We had a strange woman **come** to the door selling pictures.

2).  While others are saying **have + object + past participle**  is used to talk about an experience

> We had a strange woman **came** to the door selling pictures.

In this site I found the second form as correct. The example I found in his site - The minister had eggs **thrown** at him. (This means  The minister underwent the experience of eggs being thrown at him )

I feel that the first sentence means “We made or instructed  a strange women come to the door” and the second sentence is correct. But as an non native speaker with zero knowledge in English, I can’t question cambridge dictionary. So which of the two is correct?

Answer (score 1):

There's a confusion of types of sentences here.

There's also additional confusion because *come* is an irregular verb, and its past participle is not *came*. Its past participle is the same as its bare infinitive: *come*.

So:

1. We had a woman **come** to the door. [bare infinitive]
   I can tell this by replacing the verb with one that is not irregular:
   We had a woman **sing** to the door. [bare infinitive]
2. The minister had eggs **thrown** at him. [past participle]

But:

- The minister had a woman **throw** eggs at him. [bare infinitive]

Note how the different sentence construction changes the verb from the past participle to the bare infinitive.

None of the example sentences at Cambridge are incorrect, and they make sense within the section of the article where they're used, but since the article doesn't mention the use of the past participle at all, I find it either incomplete or slightly confusing since they chose to use an irregular verb in one of the examples (*come*).

In short, I can see why it could cause trouble for some people.

---

A site that can be used to look up conjugations, including the past participle, for most verbs is [Reverso Conjugation](https://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english.html).

Other verbs whose past participle is the same as their bare infinitive include *become*, *cost*, *cut*, *hit*, *hurt*, *let*, *put*, *read*, *run*, and *set*.